# Coloring output of forked processes

Tags: bash, colors, fork

I have a runscript that starts some processes and sends them to the background

```
mongod       & pid_mongo=$!
redis-server & pid_redis=$!
# etc.
```

All these processes then output concurrently to the same standard output. My question: is it possible to color the output of each different forked process, so that - for example - one of them outputs in green and the other one in red ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by piping through a filter, it is just a matter of adding appropriate ANSI codes before and after each line:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_sequences#Colors

I could not find a tool which actually does this after a few minutes googling, which is bit odd considering how easy it would be to write one.

Here's an idea using C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* std=gnu99 required */

// ANSI reset sequence
#define RESET "\033[0m\n"
// length of RESET
#define RLEN 5
// size for read buffer
#define BUFSZ 16384
// max length of start sequence
#define START_MAX 12

void usage (const char *name) {
    printf("Usage: %s [-1 N -2 N -b -e | -h]\n", name);
    puts("-1 is the foreground color, -2 is the background.\n"
        "'N' is one of the numbers below, corresponding to a color\n"
        "(if your terminal is not using the standard palette, these may be different):\n"
        "\t0 black\n"
        "\t1 red\n"
        "\t2 green\n"
        "\t3 yellow\n"
        "\t4 blue\n"
        "\t5 magenta\n"
        "\t6 cyan\n"
        "\t7 white\n"
        "-b sets the foreground to be brighter/bolder.\n"
        "-e will print to standard error instead of standard out.\n"
        "-h will print this message.\n"
    );
    exit (1);
}


// adds character in place and increments pointer
void appendChar (char **end, char c) {
    *(*end) = c;
    (*end)++;
}


int main (int argc, char *const argv[]) {
// no point in no arguments...
    if (argc < 2) usage(argv[0]);

// process options
    const char options[]="1:2:beh";
    int opt,
        set = 0,
        output = STDOUT_FILENO;
    char line[BUFSZ] = "\033[", // ANSI escape
        *p = &line[2];

    // loop thru options
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, options)) > 0) {
        if (p - line > START_MAX) usage(argv[0]);
        switch (opt) {
            case '?': usage(argv[0]);
            case '1': // foreground color
                if (
                    optarg[1] != '\0'
                    || optarg[0] < '0'
                    || optarg[0] > '7'
                ) usage(argv[0]);
                if (set) appendChar(&p, ';');
                appendChar(&p, '3');
                appendChar(&p, optarg[0]);
                set = 1;
                break;
            case '2': // background color
                if (
                    optarg[1] != '\0'
                    || optarg[0] < '0'
                    || optarg[0] > '7'
                ) usage(argv[0]);
                if (set) appendChar(&p, ';');
                appendChar(&p, '4');
                appendChar(&p, optarg[0]);
                set = 1;
                break;
            case 'b': // set bright/bold
                if (set) appendChar(&p, ';');
                appendChar(&p, '1');
                set = 1;
                break;
            case 'e': // use stderr
                output = STDERR_FILENO;
                break;
            case 'h': usage(argv[0]);
            default: usage(argv[0]);
        }
    }
    // finish 'start' sequence
    appendChar(&p, 'm');

// main loop

    // set non-block on input descriptor
    int flags = fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);

    // len of start sequence
    const size_t slen = p - line,
    // max length of data to read
        rmax = BUFSZ - (slen + RLEN);
    // actual amount of data read
    ssize_t r;
    // index of current position in output line
    size_t cur = slen;
    // read buffer
    char buffer[rmax];
    while ((r = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, rmax))) {
        if (!r) break;  // EOF
        if (r < 1) {
            if (errno == EAGAIN) continue;
            break;  // done, error
        }
        // loop thru input chunk byte by byte
        // this is all fine for utf-8
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            if (buffer[i] == '\n' || cur == rmax) {
            // append reset sequence
                for (int j = 0; j < RLEN; j++) line[j+cur] = RESET[j];
            // write out start sequence + buffer + reset
                write(output, line, cur+RLEN);
                cur = slen;
            } else line[cur++] = buffer[i];
        }
    }
    // write out any buffered data
    if (cur > slen) {
        for (int j = 0; j < RLEN; j++) line[j+cur] = RESET[j];
        write(output, line, cur+RLEN);
    }
    // flush
    fsync(output);

// the end
    return r;
}
```

I think that is about as efficient as you are going to get.  The `write()` needs to do an entire line with the ANSI sequences all in one go -- testing this with parallel forks led to interleaving if the ANSI sequences and the buffer content were done separately.

That needs to be compiled `-std=gnu99` since `getopt` is not part of the C99 standard but it is part of GNU.  I tested this somewhat with parallel forks; that source, a makefile, and the tests are in a tarball here:

http://cognitivedissonance.ca/cogware/utf8_colorize/utf8_colorize.tar.bz2

If the application you use this with logs to standard error, remember to redirect that too:

```
application 2>&1 | utf8-colorize -1 2 &
```

The .sh files in the test directory contain some usage examples.

Comment: Care to explain a bit further (I'm a real beginner in bash)? Do I need to add in the piping instruction before or after forking?

Comment: Before, ie. `mongod | colorfilter & pid_mongo=$!`

Comment: I've decided to goof off a bit and code something for this in C, so if you can't find anything else, come back later today or tomorrow and I'll stick a link/some source up for that.  There really should be a simple, compiled tool for this.

Comment: Awesome. I'll see what I can do on my side and look forward to comparing that with your take on it.

Comment: @louism : okay, I added some code and a link to a tarball

Comment: You should be using terminfo or termcap to get the control sequences for the terminal.  Not all `stdout` is a VT100!  But it makes little difference given that this method is flawed, with plenty of potential for races.  What you really need is a multiplexer that reads from all the writers (probably using `select()`) and colourises each block according to which fd it was read from.

Comment: @TobySpeight I admit to not having used this much myself and there's certainly much to improve upon -- by writing more code, which I haven't since it isn't that important to me.  However (as noted in the answer) this actually *doesn't* produce any interleaving when tested, presumably because of `stdout` buffering (put another way, 
*the race condition is no different than it would be without any filter;* if your tish is interleaving already, this will not fix it, but it will not create it either).  It's a quick hack method, that's all.

Answer (score 5):

```
red=$(tput setaf 1)
green=$(tput setaf 2)
default=$(tput sgr0)
cmd1 2>&1 | sed "s/.*/$red&$default/" &
cmd2 2>&1 | sed "s/.*/$green&$default/" &
```

Comment: +1 To test, define e.g. `cmd1() { while true; do echo foo; sleep 1; done }` and `cmd2() { while true; do echo bar; sleep 3; done }`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better of redirecting the logs to specific output files?

There are many different solutions for colorizing output. The easiest probably would be to use the [grc](http://wynnnetherland.com/journal/a-stylesheet-author-s-guide-to-terminal-colors) package..

Comment: Redirecting to separate files is not the best option if a) you are trying to observe/debug something in real time. b) you want the order of events from multiple processes preserved without having to compare time-stamps in separate files.  I would guess the OP is testing a front end server combined with a back-end database server (mongo) and wants to see what happens when.

Answer (score 0):

another option you can use with sh built in function:
works also on ash (busybox) ;)

```
RED=`echo -e '\033[0;31m'`
NC=`echo -e '\033[0m'` # No Color

cmdx 2>&1 | sed "s/.*/$RED&$NC/" &
```

I wrote myself a shell function to easily run programs in the background. This is writen for busybox' ash! Works in bash as well.
Just run:

```
bg_red <whatever cmd you want to run in the bg>
```

put following into your .bashrc

```
ESC="\033"                                                                      
# Colors:
COLOR_RED_F="${ESC}[31m"
COLOR_GREEN_F="${ESC}[32m" 
COLOR_RESET="${ESC}[0m" 

bg_red()            
{                                                                               
   [ "$#" -lt "1" ] && echo "bg_red() <cmd to run in bg>" && return 1           
   PIPE_RED=`echo -e $COLOR_RED_F`                                              
   PIPE_NC=`echo -e $COLOR_RESET`                                               
   $@ 2>&1 | sed "s/.*/$PIPE_RED&$PIPE_NC/" &                                   
}
```

as seen here:
http://www.bramschoenmakers.nl/en/node/511.html